# Word2vec word index is different from keras tokenizer word index

Tags: python, keras, word2vec

I am using word2vec to train and obtain embedding matrix. But, the dictionary contains word index that starts from 0.

[image: Dictionary of word2vec]

Then, i also get embedding matrix whose index also starts from 0
[image]

However, when I use keras tokenizer, i get words whose index starting from 1[image]
Here is my embedding layer that I pass the embedding matrix as weight.

```
embedded = Embedding(len(embeddings.vocab),
    output_dim = output_dim,
    input_length = test_X.shape[1],
    weights=[embeddings_matrix],
    trainable=True)(_input)
```

My input data is like

```
arr = [
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4],
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,2,5,4],
.....
]
```

Then, i use pad_sequence on my array and i get

```
arr = [
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,2,5,4,0,0]
]
```

The 0 here is just to pad sequence to have all same length. But, it will be represented by the vector of index 0 of my embedding matrix, which is wrong. How could I deal with that?

Comment: did u use another value for padding instead of zero?

Answer (score 0):

From the [pad_sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences) docs :

> Parameter : value =   Float or String, padding value. (Optional, defaults to 0.)

So you can do something like

```
pad_sequences(sequence, value='PAD')
```

Which should change the array to:

```
arr = [
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,'PAD','PAD','PAD','PAD','PAD','PAD','PAD'],
    [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,2,5,4,'PAD','PAD']
]
```

And hopefully removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Here, you could change 0 to PAD, but the point is one array start from 0 (0->7) and the other one starts from 1 (1->8) . So, so it will point to wrong embedding matrix by index.